# Thread safety clarification in a c library

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, posix, shared-libraries

Can someone clarify to me if the following piece of code is thread safety?

```
int get_time(uint64_t *time)
{
    struct timespec spec;
    if (!time)
        return -EFAULT;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec) == -1)
        return -errno;
    *time = //convert timespec into nanoseconds
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

This is an API in a library that could be called by multiple threads.
The spec is a local variable so it not should be a problem. Correct? My doubt is about the clock_getime (POSIX.1-2001) and the assignment to the time argument. I would to introduce a mutex, but I'm not sure if it is strictly required.

Comment: I don't see a good reason to think that this function is not thread safe. I can't find a reference to it, but why would `clock_gettime()` be thread-unsafe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't using anything but automatic variables in your code, and the only function-call ([`clock_gettime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html)) is inherently thread-safe, so the answer is:

Yes, it's safe.

[From the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_396):

> #### 3.396 Thread-Safe
>
> A function that may be safely invoked concurrently by multiple threads. Each function defined in the System Interfaces volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 is **thread-safe unless explicitly stated otherwise**. Examples are any "pure" function, a function which holds a mutex locked while it is accessing static storage, or objects shared among threads.

There is no exception listed on the spec for that function:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html

Comment: Thank you. My doubt about the clock_gettime was that I found in the man page that it conforms to POSIX.1-2001, and i read this whitepaper http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/reentrant.html. It's possible that I misunderstood

Comment: my fault... the white paper is about the reentrancy, not the thread safety. Thank you

Comment: Ofcourse it is not thread safe, assignement to *time needs a lock. How do you prevent threads to read/write *time concurrently?